# egrep, sed or awk to get the number of active dhcp leases?

Tags: text-processing, freebsd, isc-dhcpd

Let's say I have the following dhcpd.leases file:

```
# The format of this file is documented in the dhcpd.leases(5) manual page.
# This lease file was written by isc-dhcp-4.3.6-P1

# authoring-byte-order entry is generated, DO NOT DELETE
authoring-byte-order little-endian;

lease 10.1.1.108 {
  ...
  starts 3 2020/03/04 08:23:54;
  ends 3 2020/03/04 13:49:03;
  tstp 3 2020/03/04 13:49:03;
  cltt 3 2020/03/04 08:23:54;
  binding state free;
  ...
}
lease 10.1.1.109 {
  ...
  starts 3 2020/03/04 13:43:00;
  ends 3 2020/03/04 13:49:44;
  tstp 3 2020/03/04 13:49:44;
  cltt 3 2020/03/04 13:43:00;
  binding state free;
  ...
}
lease 10.1.2.100 {
  ...
  starts 6 2020/03/28 12:49:45;
  ends 0 2020/03/29 12:49:45;
  tstp 0 2020/03/29 12:49:45;
  cltt 6 2020/03/28 12:49:45;
  binding state active;
  ...
lease 10.1.1.104 {
  ...
  starts 6 2020/03/28 18:53:45;
  ends 0 2020/03/29 18:53:45;
  tstp 0 2020/03/29 18:53:45;
  cltt 6 2020/03/28 18:53:45;
  binding state active;
  ...
}
```

I'd like to extract the number of active DHCP leases for each subnet, something like this for this example:

```
10.1.1.0/24: 1
10.1.2.0/24: 1
```

Now, I've seen numerous questions here about the dhcpd.leases file but most of the answers are related towards outputting the Mac Address for each IP, which is not what I'm looking for here. The problem with the commands I've tried is I can't figure out how to exclude completely the inactive leases, can't figure out how to split the subnets and can't out which tool I should really use for this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is some stuff I tried, no idea if I'm on the right path, been playing for hours with these commands...

```
egrep "lease|active|\}" /var/dhcpd/var/db/dhcpd.leases
sed -e '/lease/,/active/!d' /var/dhcpd/var/db/dhcpd.leases
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\n"; RS="}";} {print $2}' /var/dhcpd/var/db/dhcpd.leases
```

Doesn't really do what I want it to do however.

Note: I am on pfSense (FreeBSD).

Comment: You might want to take a look at `dhcpd-pools` (http://dhcpd-pools.sourceforge.net/). And if you have `jq` in addition, you could use the JSON output format to process it easily (maybe something like `dhcpd-pools -fj | jq -r '.subnets[] | [.range, .used] | @tsv'`)

Comment: @muru This is on pfSense so I don't necessarily want to install packages for security reasons but I could easily ssh from a local VM to get the file locally and work with jq from there if that's easier to do that way. dhcpd-pools isn't installed by default on pfSense or FreeBSD but that might not be as much of a security issue as jq.

Comment: Seems like `dhcpd-pools` is kinda complicated to get working on pfSense/FreeBSD after looking it up. I'll edit my question to specify that I'm on pfSense.

Comment: Make sure your script works with real IP addresses (IPv6), not only vintage ones.

Comment: I ended up adapting https://askubuntu.com/a/553387/104514, I guess I'm better at Python. This is slightly overkill but not that bad. As for DHCPv6... I don't think this will be a huge problem (I don't really use IPv6 so far since my ISP doesn't support it to its full extent), if the entries are similar in the dhcpd.leases file this should still work, otherwise I will adapt. I will post my final script as the answer once I'm done.

Answer (score 0):

All right so, after more research, I decided to adapt this Python script for my purpose:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/219609/how-do-i-show-active-dhcp-leases/553387#553387

Also, my network topology here is known, fixed and doesn't change, so the little maths I do at the end are taking this into consideration but you can easily change it to whatever you need. And finally, since all of this was ultimately for a Checkmk monitoring chart script, the output is presented in the way Checkmk needs it to parse it. Anyways, without further ado, here it is:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import datetime, bisect

def left(s, amount):
    return s[:amount]

def right(s, amount):
    return s[-amount:]

def mid(s, offset, amount):
    return s[offset:offset+amount]

def parse_timestamp(raw_str):
        tokens = raw_str.split()

        if len(tokens) == 1:
                if tokens[0].lower() == 'never':
                        return 'never';
                else:
                        raise Exception('Parse error in timestamp')
        elif len(tokens) == 3:
                return datetime.datetime.strptime(' '.join(tokens[1:]),'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
        else:
                raise Exception('Parse error in timestamp')

def timestamp_is_ge(t1, t2):
        if t1 == 'never':
                return True
        elif t2 == 'never':
                return False
        else:
                return t1 >= t2

def timestamp_is_lt(t1, t2):
        if t1 == 'never':
                return False
        elif t2 == 'never':
                return t1 != 'never'
        else:
                return t1 < t2

def timestamp_is_between(t, tstart, tend):
        return timestamp_is_ge(t, tstart) and timestamp_is_lt(t, tend)

def parse_hardware(raw_str):
        tokens = raw_str.split()

        if len(tokens) == 2:
                return tokens[1]
        else:
                raise Exception('Parse error in hardware')

def strip_endquotes(raw_str):
        return raw_str.strip('"')

def identity(raw_str):
        return raw_str

def parse_binding_state(raw_str):
        tokens = raw_str.split()

        if len(tokens) == 2:
                return tokens[1]
        else:
                raise Exception('Parse error in binding state')

def parse_next_binding_state(raw_str):
        tokens = raw_str.split()

        if len(tokens) == 3:
                return tokens[2]
        else:
                raise Exception('Parse error in next binding state')

def parse_rewind_binding_state(raw_str):
        tokens = raw_str.split()

        if len(tokens) == 3:
                return tokens[2]
        else:
                raise Exception('Parse error in next binding state')

def parse_leases_file(leases_file):
        valid_keys = {
                'starts':               parse_timestamp,
                'ends':                 parse_timestamp,
                'tstp':                 parse_timestamp,
                'tsfp':                 parse_timestamp,
                'atsfp':                parse_timestamp,
                'cltt':                 parse_timestamp,
                'hardware':             parse_hardware,
                'binding':              parse_binding_state,
                'next':                 parse_next_binding_state,
                'rewind':               parse_rewind_binding_state,
                'uid':                  strip_endquotes,
                'client-hostname':      strip_endquotes,
                'option':               identity,
                'set':                  identity,
                'on':                   identity,
                'abandoned':            None,
                'bootp':                None,
                'reserved':             None,
                }

        leases_db = {}
        lease_rec = {}
        in_lease = False
        in_failover = False

        for line in leases_file:
                if line.lstrip().startswith('#'):
                        continue

                tokens = line.split()

                if len(tokens) == 0:
                        continue

                key = tokens[0].lower()

                if key == 'lease':
                        if not in_lease:
                                ip_address = tokens[1]
                                lease_rec = {'ip_address' : ip_address}
                                in_lease = True
                        else:
                                raise Exception('Parse error in leases file')

                elif key == 'failover':
                        in_failover = True
                elif key == '}':
                        if in_lease:
                                for k in valid_keys:
                                        if callable(valid_keys[k]):
                                                lease_rec[k] = lease_rec.get(k, '')
                                        else:
                                                lease_rec[k] = False

                                ip_address = lease_rec['ip_address']

                                if ip_address in leases_db:
                                        leases_db[ip_address].insert(0, lease_rec)
                                else:
                                        leases_db[ip_address] = [lease_rec]

                                lease_rec = {}
                                in_lease = False
                        elif in_failover:
                                in_failover = False
                                continue
                        else:
                                raise Exception('Parse error in leases file')
                elif key in valid_keys:
                        if in_lease:
                                value = line[(line.index(key) + len(key)):]
                                value = value.strip().rstrip(';').rstrip()

                                if callable(valid_keys[key]):
                                        lease_rec[key] = valid_keys[key](value)
                                else:
                                        lease_rec[key] = True
                        else:
                                raise Exception('Parse error in leases file')
                else:
                        if in_lease:
                                raise Exception('Parse error in leases file')
        if in_lease:
                raise Exception('Parse error in leases file')
        return leases_db

def round_timedelta(tdelta):
        return datetime.timedelta(tdelta.days,
                tdelta.seconds + (0 if tdelta.microseconds < 500000 else 1))

def timestamp_now():
        n = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        return datetime.datetime(n.year, n.month, n.day, n.hour, n.minute,
                n.second + (0 if n.microsecond < 500000 else 1))

def lease_is_active(lease_rec, as_of_ts):
        return timestamp_is_between(as_of_ts, lease_rec['starts'],
                lease_rec['ends'])

def ipv4_to_int(ipv4_addr):
        parts = ipv4_addr.split('.')
        return (int(parts[0]) << 24) + (int(parts[1]) << 16) + \
                (int(parts[2]) << 8) + int(parts[3])

def select_active_leases(leases_db, as_of_ts):
        retarray = []
        sortedarray = []

        for ip_address in leases_db:
                lease_rec = leases_db[ip_address][0]

                if lease_is_active(lease_rec, as_of_ts):
                        ip_as_int = ipv4_to_int(ip_address)
                        insertpos = bisect.bisect(sortedarray, ip_as_int)
                        sortedarray.insert(insertpos, ip_as_int)
                        retarray.insert(insertpos, lease_rec)
        return retarray

myfile = open('/var/dhcpd/var/db/dhcpd.leases', 'r')
leases = parse_leases_file(myfile)
myfile.close()

now = timestamp_now()
report_dataset = select_active_leases(leases, now)
lan_leases = sum(map(lambda x : left(x['ip_address'],7)=='10.1.1.', report_dataset))
wlan_leases = sum(map(lambda x : left(x['ip_address'],8)=='10.20.1.', report_dataset))
wlan_guest_leases = sum(map(lambda x : left(x['ip_address'],8)=='10.20.2.', report_dataset))
wlan_appliance_leases = sum(map(lambda x : left(x['ip_address'],8)=='10.20.3.', report_dataset))

print('0 dhcp_leases lan_leases=' + str(lan_leases) + '|wlan_leases=' + str(wlan_leases) + '|wlan_guest_leases=' + str(wlan_guest_leases) + '|wlan_appliance_leases=' + str(wlan_appliance_leases) + ' ' + str(lan_leases) + ' LAN lease(s), ' + str(wlan_leases) + ' WLAN lease(s), ' + str(wlan_guest_leases) + ' WLAN_GUEST lease(s), ' + str(wlan_appliance_leases) + ' WLAN_APPLIANCE lease(s)')
```